# Replacing recursion with transitive closure (reachability and productivity of non-terminals)

Tags: alloy

Sometimes, when I would like to use recursion in Alloy, I find I can get by with transitive closure, or sequences.

For example, in a model of context-free grammars:

```
abstract sig Symbol {}
sig NT, T extends Symbol {}

// A grammar is a tuple(V, Sigma, Rules, Start) 
one sig Grammar {
  V : set NT,
  Sigma : set T,
  Rules : set Prod,
  Start : one V
}

// A production rule has a left-hand side
// and a right-hand side
sig Prod {
  lhs : NT,
  rhs : seq Symbol
}

fact tidy_world {
  // Don't fill the model with irrelevancies
  Prod in Grammar.Rules
  Symbol in (Grammar.V + Grammar.Sigma)
}
```

One possible definition of reachable non-terminals would be "the start symbol, and any non-terminal appearing on the right-hand side of a rule for a reachable symbol."  A straightforward translation would be

```
// A non-terminal 'refers' to non-terminals
// in the right-hand sides of its rules
pred refers[n1, n2 : NT] {
  let r = (Grammar.Rules & lhs.n1) |
  n2 in r.rhs.elems
}

pred reachable[n : NT] {
  n in Grammar.Start
  or some n2 : NT 
    | (reachable[n2] and refers[n2,n])
}
```

Predictably, this blows the stack.  But if we simply take the transitive closure of Grammar.Start under the `refers` relation (or, strictly speaking, a relation formed from the `refers` predicate), we can define reachability:

```
// A non-terminal is 'reachable' if it's the
// start symbol or if it is referred to by
// (rules for) a reachable symbol.
pred Reachable[n : NT] {
  n in Grammar.Start.*(
    {n1, n2 : NT | refers[n1,n2]}
  )
}

pred some_unreachable {
  some n : (NT - Grammar.Start) 
    | not Reachable[n]
}
run some_unreachable for 4
```

In principle, the definition of productive symbols is similarly recursive: a symbol is productive iff it is a terminal symbol, or it has at least one rule in which every symbol in the right-hand side is productive.  The simple-minded way to write this is

```
pred productive[s : Symbol] {
  s in T 
  or some p : (lhs.s) | 
      all r : (p.rhs.elems) | productive[r]
}
```

Like the straightforward definition of reachability, this blows the stack.  But I have not yet found a relation I can define on symbols which will give me, via transitive closure, the result I want.  Have I found a case where transitive closure cannot substitute for recursion?  Or have I just not thought hard enough to find the right relation?

There is an obvious, if laborious, hack:

```
pred p0[s : Symbol] { s in T }
pred p1[s : Symbol] { p0[s] 
  or some p : (lhs.s) 
  | all e : p.rhs.elems 
  | p0[e]}
pred p2[s : Symbol] { p1[s] 
  or some p : (lhs.s) 
  | all e : p.rhs.elems 
  | p1[e]}
pred p3[s : Symbol] { p2[s] 
  or some p : (lhs.s) 
  | all e : p.rhs.elems 
  | p2[e]}
... etc ...
pred productive[n : NT] {
  p5[n]
}
```

This works OK as long as one doesn't forget to add enough predicates to handle the longest possible chain of non-terminal references, if one raises the scope.

Concretely, I seem to have several questions; answers to any of them would be welcome:

1 Is there a way to define the set of productive non-terminals in Alloy without resorting to the p0, p1, p2, ... hack?

2 If one does have to resort to the hack, is there a better way to define it?

3 As a theoretical question:  is it possible to characterize the set of recursive predicates that can be defined using transitive closure, or sequences of atoms, instead of recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have I found a case where transitive closure cannot substitute for recursion?

Yes, that is the case. More precisely, you found a recursive relation that cannot be expressed with the first-order transitive closure (that is supported in Alloy).

> Is there a way to define the set of productive non-terminals in Alloy without resorting to the p0, p1, p2, ... hack? If one does have to resort to the hack, is there a better way to define it?

There is no a way to do this in Alloy. However, there might be a way to do this in [Alloy*](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/hola/) which supports higher-order quantification. (The idea would be to describe the set of productive elements with a closure over the relation of "productiveness", which would use second-order quantification over the set of productive symbols, and constraining this set to be minimal. Similar idea is described in "A.1.9  Axiomatizing Transitive Closure" in the Alloy book.)

> As a theoretical question: is it possible to characterize the set of recursive predicates that can be defined using transitive closure, or sequences of atoms, instead of recursion?

This is an interesting question. The [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_logic) article mentions relative expressiveness of second order logic when transitive closure and fixed point operator are added (the later being able to express forms of recursion).